# How to autoselect first item from jQuery autocomplete list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

In the below screenshot how can I auto select the first item from jQuery autocomplete list if no item is selected?

[image]

Required JS code at http://pastebin.com/ThVpLSvC Site link https://dev.ther8server.com (Please excuse the self signed SSL). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
                 <script>
                $(function() {
                var availableTags = [
                "1001",
                "1002",
                "1003",
                "1004",
                "1005",
                "1006",
                "1007",
                "1008",
                "1009",
                "1010",
                "1011",
                "1012",
                "1013",
                "1014",
                "1015",
                "1016",
                "1017",
                "1018",
                "1019",
                "1020",
                "1021",
                ];
                $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags,
                select: function(){
                $('#page1_block').show();
                }
                });
                });
                </script>
```